# Parse Android startup

Tags: android, parse-platform

Just gone trough the tutorial and added every code as described. But I still get no response from my app. Does it have to be published in Google Play before Parse starts to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no need for being published before it works. Just get the code right :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parse objects. Include,

```
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.saveInBackground();
```

And enter other codes correctly. No need to publish in google play. You can test it.